# gray background when opening and closing modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working with modal bootstrap, and use the click event of the button to close this modal: before I only used this command: and this worked normally

```
$('#AddContact').click(function(){
    $("#ModalContact").modal('hide');    
});
```

but now I'm having to use this to accomplish the same task, **why did this update occur**? is it any effect in css or html?

```
$('#AddContact').click(function(){
    $("#ModalContact").modal('hide');
    $('body').removeClass('modal-open');
    $('.modal-backdrop').remove();
});
```

and now has another problem, when I try to open the model a second time after closing using the second function, the model does not appear, leaving only a gray screen overwriting the current body. How can I solve this?

```
<a  href="" data-toggle="modal"  data-target="#ModalContact"> Add Contact</a>
```

*button event to open the modal*

```
<!-- Modal Contato -->
<div class="modal fade " id="ModalContact" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">

            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" class="close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
                <h4 id="exampleModalLabel" class="modal-title">Contato</h4>

            </div>

            <div class="modal-body" id="CamposAddContato">



            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">

                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default  BotaoPadrao" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
                <button type="button" id="AddContact" class="btn btn-success  BotaoPadrao">Salvar</button>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think this line `$('.modal-backdrop').remove();` is removing your modal, Can you provide your HTML code related to the modal?

Comment: Why not just put `data-dismiss="modal"` on #AddContact?

Answer (score 3):

Taking into account your code, I don't see what is the problem, here is a code snippet.

```js
  $('#AddContact').click(function(){

    $("#ModalContact").modal('hide');
    $('body').removeClass('modal-open');
    $('.modal-backdrop').remove();  

  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<a  href="" data-toggle="modal"  data-target="#ModalContact"> Add Contact</a>


<!-- Modal Contato -->
<div class="modal fade " id="ModalContact" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">

            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" class="close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
                <h4 id="exampleModalLabel" class="modal-title">
                  Contato
                </h4>

            </div>

            <div class="modal-body" id="CamposAddContato">
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ....</p>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">

                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default  BotaoPadrao" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
                <button type="button" id="AddContact" class="btn btn-success  BotaoPadrao">Salvar</button>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I removed it, and my problem still continues when I click on the button to open the modal the second time it causes the same error

Comment: Can you provide the entire code of your issue? HTML and JavaScript

Comment: I added the modal code that was all I needed because it opens with the <a> target and closes when I click on btnadd, was that it?

Comment: Take a look the answer again, I don't see any problem on your code.

Comment: Wow, how strange I'm going to try to redo the code. thanks for listening :/

Comment: You're welcome. If you think that my answer fit your need, please I invite you to mark it as **the correct answer**

Comment: I'm sorry but your answer did not help me, this was just a modal tutorial that is easily found on the bootstrap site. but thanks for your attention

Comment: Ok, no problem. Good luck and happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because you are using some position property in css which causes this problem. an easy method to solve this is to change the method of opening the modal, rather than open with the target is then opened with a jquery function

```
<!--
<a  href="" data-toggle="modal"  data-target="#ModalContato"> Adicionar Contato</a>-->
<a id="AbrirModalContato" href="" > Adicionar Contato</a>


    $('#AbrirModalContato').click(function(){
        $('#ModalContato').appendTo("body").modal('show');
        return false; 
    });
```